# How to truncate a file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, truncate

I am writing actions done by the program in C# into a file by using Trace.Writeln() function. But the file is becoming too large. How to truncate this file when it grows to 1MB?

```
TextWriterTraceListener traceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(File.AppendText("audit.txt"));
Trace.Listeners.Add(traceListener);
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
```

What should be added to the above block

Comment: You should specify what part(s) of the log you want to keep.

Answer (score 42):

Try to play around with [FileStream.SetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx)

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...);
fileStream.SetLength(sizeInBytesNotChars);
```

Comment: +1 If OP is using `FileStream` this is the simplest solution, using `SetLength(0)`.

Comment: After terminating the process, if I recreate a new process then the above code will append the text to the existing file?

Comment: If you do `SetLength(0)` on an active `FileStream`, that will truncate the underlying file.

Comment: We note that FileStream.SetLength with a non-zero length is a very bad idea for a log file; however I found this question with a more reasonable case where this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 12):

Close the file and then reopen it using [FileMode.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx).

Some log implementations archive the old file under an old name before reopening it, to preserve a larger set of data without any file getting too big.

Comment: This will truncate the file down to 0 bytes, i.e. you throw away the whole thing. That might be what the OP wants to do...or they might want to keep some of it, in which case don't do this.

Answer (score 6):

As opposed to trying to do this yourself, I'd really recommend using something like log4net; it has a lot of this sort of useful functionality built in.

Comment: Since you're not actually answering the question, this should be a comment.

Comment: @Gabe: I don't think it's an inappropriate answer to a question to answer that the OP's stated method shows some inefficiencies, and to suggest an alternate method.

Comment: Good answers show code or link to the specific function to use. If you want this to be a good answer, show how to use log4net to do what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 6):

When the file is over 500000 bytes, it will cut the beginning 250000 bytes off from the file so the remaining file is 250000 bytes long.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
if (fs.Length > 500000)
{
    // Set the length to 250Kb
    Byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    fs.Close();
    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create);
    fs2.Write(bytes, (int)bytes.Length - 250000, 250000);
    fs2.Flush();
} // end if (fs.Length > 500000)
```

Comment: This reads the whole file into memory. Not ideal if it's really big.

Comment: If you're going to discard the first 25k bytes from the follow, you don't need to read it.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this:

```
if(new FileInfo("<your file path>").Length > 1000000)
{
    File.WriteAllText("<your file path>", "");
}
```

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the value `1000000`... remember, `1 kbyte = 1024 bytes`, and the same applies for `mb`

Comment: Personally I would not check the file length this way, it's going to require a lot of `new FileInfo` calls (one per write).  Most likely the class the OP is using to write to the file has some way to track the size, if it's a `FileStream` for example use the `Position` property.

Comment: @Oscar: I know, it's just to give the main idea, it needs to be adapted.

Comment: this wouldn't be able to do a rolling log.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no desire to keep the contents, or move them into a subsidiary file that tracks the update for the cycle (whether by day or some other cycle length), I would recommend just rewriting the file using this simple method:

```
private void Truncate(readFile)     // to clear contents of file and note last time it was cleared
{
    string readFile = readPath + ".txt";
    string str = string.Format("{0} : Truncated Contents", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
    using (StreamWriter truncate = new StreamWriter(readFile))
    {
        truncate.WriteLine(str); // truncates and leaves the message with DateTime stamp
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to save the contents to a file for the date they were truncated, you can use the following method in conjunction with the above:

```
private void Truncate(readPath)     // to clear contents of file, copy, and note last time it was cleared and copied
{
    if (!File.Exists(readPath))    // create the new file for storing old entries
    {
        string readFile = readPath + ".txt";
        string writeFile = readPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("_dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm") + ".txt"; // you can add all the way down to milliseconds if your system runs fast enough
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(writeFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fs))
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(readFile))
            {
                write.WriteLine(string.Format(textA, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                string line;
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Replace("\0", ""); // removes nonsense bits from stream
                    sb.AppendLine(line);
                }
                write.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                string textB = "{0} : Copied Source";
                write.WriteLine(string.Format(textB, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
            }
        }
        string str = string.Format("{0} : Truncated Contents", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
        using (StreamWriter truncate = new StreamWriter(readFile))
        {
            truncate.WriteLine(str); // truncates and leaves the message with DateTime stamp
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, you can utilize the method of your choice with the following block:

```
if(new FileInfo("audit.txt").Length >= 0xfffff) // hex for 1MB
{
    Truncate("audit");
}
```

I hope this helps future readers.

Thanks,

C§

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be simple solution:

```
// Test the file is more or equal to a 1MB ((1 * 1024) * 1024)
// There are 1024B in 1KB, 1024KB in 1MB
if (new FileInfo(file).length >= ((1 * 1024) * 1024))
{
    // This will open your file. Once opened, it will write all data to 0
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Write to your file.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you might try:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(YourFileName, false);
sw.Write("");
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Sending `false` as the second param of `StreamWriter()` tells it NOT to append, resulting in it overwriting the file.  In this case with an empty string, effectively truncating it.