# Json format broke after saving

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net, filestream

So I have an application with a List. I store this List in a json file and while the application is running I make changes to the list and save it as .json file on disk.

Before the application is closed by the user I would like to reset some values. On that save right before the application is close the format of the json is not saved correctly. Resulting in a invalid json file.

**Close:**

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var customer in _currentCustomers) {
      customer.State = TransferState.None;
      customer.NextScan = String.Empty;
   }
   WriteCustomerList();
   this.Close();
}
```

**WriteCustomerList Method:**

```
try
{
      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appConfigLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
     {
        using (var br = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {

           br.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_currentCustomers)));

         }
      }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Failed to write customer list./n/n" + ex.Message, "Error!");
}
```

**Correct Json:**

```
[{
    "Username": "xxxxx",
    "Password": "xxxx",
    "RelationNumber": "xxxx",
    "State": 3,
    "NextScan": "",
    "Interval": 1
}]
```

**Json After closing:**

```
[{
    "Username": "xxx",
    "Password": "xxxx",
    "RelationNumber": "xxxx",
    "State": 3,
    "NextScan": "",
    "Interval": 1
}]26","Interval":1}]
```

Comment: Are you writing all of the data each time? If so, `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` could be the problem if the file if longer than the new data you are writing. You probably would want `FileMode.Truncate`.

Comment: Yes i'm just overwriting the all data each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't truncate file so previous content is still there (resulting in whatever is after first `]`).

In your case using [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be safer and shorter solution:

```
File.WriteAllText(_appConfigLocation,
     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_currentCustomers));
```

If you need more control - use `FileMode.Truncate` or other approaches recommended in [How to truncate a file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537926/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c).

Comment: Ah great this works. I will pay around with both solutions to see what suits best here. Thank you!