# Open, Lock, Truncate and Write to a file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to replicate Excel's behaviour when opening and editing files, that is:

- File is opened and locked for exclusive write access
- Other users are allowed to read the file

I'm using the following code to open the file, read and prepare for later writing:

```
_fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
_fileReader = new StreamReader(_fileStream);
_fileWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileStream);
var contents = _fileReader.ReadToEnd();
```

(In a class that implements IDisposable and disposes the streams)

It apparently works fine aside from one issue when I later save using the following code:

```
_fileWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
_fileWriter.Write(content);
_fileWriter.Flush();
```

The problem is that I need to truncate the file before saving, and the above only overwrites. If the new content is shorter than what was loaded, I end up with a bad file due to partial old content.

How do I truncate a filestream before writing (but not before reading)?

Is there perhaps a better way to gain exclusive access to the file than what I am doing?

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks. I found another way, but SetLength is an even simpler option, so I'll replace my code with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't think of this until now, but I found my answer in the source code for System.IO.File:

```
[SecurityCritical]
private static void InternalWriteAllText(
  string path,
  string contents,
  Encoding encoding,
  bool checkHost)
{
  using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding, 1024, checkHost))
    streamWriter.Write(contents);
}
```

I didn't realize that I could safely open the file for writing, not from the existing FileStream, but by specifying the path. This allowed me to set `append` to false.

EDIT:

A simpler solution is found in this answer: [How to truncate a file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537926/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c)

Just call `SetLength(0)` before writing.

Comment: Please note that you can't share a FileStream between multiple StreamReader/StreamWriter instances.  The FileShare.xxx options control how multiple handles/FileStreams can be used against the same file.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Hm.. I had actually expected that to be the case, but I've yet to encounter adverse effects of doing so. What sort of problems should I be seeing as it appears to work fine? And how would I then lock a file for Write elsewhere yet allow my own application to write to it?

Comment: The Readers and Writers have internal buffers, and expect  the FileStream location to _not change_ without them knowing about it.   The FileStream has only _one_ Location at which the next Read or Write will occur.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Ah thank you very much. The reason I'm not seeing it is because I only use the Reader once. I'll refactor my code just to guard against future changes.